# SSIS Error When executing from command line

Tags: ssis

I have a small SSIS package which exports data to a excel file from SQL server 2008. The package works perfectly fine in our dev environment, when the package is moved to our another environment we receive the below error on execution from command line.
The package runs for a while and then gives the below error

```
Error: 2012-05-21 18:34:01.61
   Code: 0xC000F427
   Source: Create Summary From Detail SSIS.Pipeline
   Description: To run a SSIS package outside of Business Intelligence 
   Development Studio you must install Standard Edition of Integration Services 
   or higher.
End Error
```

Other SSIS packages which were exported to this environment before are working fine now. Only this package is throwing this error, what i meant to say is we are having the SSIS installed on this environment.

Can Some one please let me know what could be the possible reason for this?
Please let me know if you need more information.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of SQL Server do you have installed on your computer?  You need at least SQL Server 2005 Standard Edition.  If you are running Workgroup Edition or SQL Server Express, you will have difficulties with advanced SSIS features (unless you are running through Visual Studio.)

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx#SSIS for a list of SSIS features not supported by SQL Server Workgroup.

Answer (score 0):

A package runs on the same computer as the program that launches it. Even when a program loads a package that is stored remotely on another server, the package runs on the local computer. Also, you can only run a package outside the development environment on a computer that has Integration Services installed. You cannot run packages outside of Business Intelligence Development Studio on a client computer that does not have Integration Services installed, and the terms of your SQL Server 2005 licensing may not permit you to install Integration Services on additional computers.

So, apparently you don't have SSIS on your "another environment". Did you deploy it to SQl Server or File disk?

> To run remote packages from a local computer that does not have
>   Integration Services installed, start the packages so that they run on
>   the remote computer on which Integration Services is installed. You do
>   this by having the local computer use SQL Server Agent, a Web service,
>   or a remote component to start the packages on the remote computer. If
>   you try to start the remote packages directly from the local computer,
>   the packages will load onto and try to run from the local computer. If
>   the local computer does not have Integration Services installed, the
>   packages will not run.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403355%28SQL.90%29.aspx) article shows mechanisms for running the package on another machine that does have SSIS installed:

Comment: @Diego...Thanks for you quick reply.....As i mentioned above in my question, SSIS is installed on the machine and other packages are being executed fine. This is the only package which is throwing that error....

Comment: but how was it deployed? how is it called and is it calling any other child packages?

Comment: It is deployed using the Source Control(as other packages were deployed), the package is being called from commnad line, and it is only a single package no child packages are associated with it

Comment: is it deployed on the file system, sql server or SSIS package store?

Comment: @ Diego ...It is deployed on File System